# Toggle content after a radio button is checked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I fix the issue? I would like to toggle the content of the each radio button if it's selected. Also how could I set the default selected radio button?

```js
$(".option-detail").hide();
$(".option").click(function() {
  $(this).next('div').slideToggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="option">Option 1
      <div class="option-detail">Some content here</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="option">Option 2
      <div class="option-detail">Some content here</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" class="option">Option 3
      <div class="option-detail">Some content here</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your radio buttons need names. And you select a default by adding the checked attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**Relevant Spec - 17 Forms / 17.2.1 Control types**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1)
>
> Radio buttons are like checkboxes except that when **several share the same control name, they are mutually exclusive**: when one is switched "on", all others with the same name are switched "off".

Thus, the radio elements need to share a common name attribute in order for them to be mutually exclusive.

```
<input type="radio" name="group" class="option">
```

```
$(':input').on('change', function() {
  $(".option-detail").slideUp();
  $(this).parent('label').next('div').slideToggle(this.checked);
});
```

Changes I made:

- I wrapped the `input` elements with `label` elements in order to increase usability. In doing so, you can now click on the text or the radio button in order to trigger a change event.
- I changed the event from `click` to `change`.
- I slided all the `.option-detail` elements up each time an event is fired. In doing so, only one is displayed at once.

If you want a radio button to be selected by default, add the `checked` attribute to it.

```
<input type="radio" name="group" class="option" checked>
```

or

```
<input type="radio" name="group" class="option" checked="checked">
```

```js
$(".option-detail").hide();

$(':input').on('change', function() {
  $(".option-detail").slideUp();
  $(this).parent('label').next('div').slideToggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label><input type="radio" name="group" class="option" checked>Option 1</label>
      <div class="option-detail">Some content here</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label><input type="radio" name="group" class="option">Option 2</label>
      <div class="option-detail">Some content here</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label><input type="radio" name="group" class="option">Option 3</label>
      <div class="option-detail">Some content here</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, as always very helpful and comprehensive answer on the issue!