# Angular2/Ionic2 - Toggle content after a radio button is checked

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have 3 radio button, in which I want to show a particular content once of them is checked, currently here is my code that show present the 3 radio buttons:

```
 <ion-list radio-group>
    <ion-item class="listItems">
        <ion-label>Option 1</ion-label>
        <ion-radio checked="false" value="Option1"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="listItems">
        <ion-label>Option 2</ion-label>
        <ion-radio checked="false" value="Option2"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="listItems">
        <ion-label>Option 3</ion-label>
        <ion-radio checked="false" value="Option3"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

I've found a [codepen](http://codepen.io/SusanneLundblad/pen/iBhoJ) written in Angular1 that shows/hides content when a radio button is check, I've tried to play with it to make it work in my ionic2/angular2 project; however, it didn't worked!

I've also found a thread in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442959/toggle-content-after-a-radio-button-is-checked-using-jquery) for ***Toggle content after a radio button is checked using jQuery*** but I was not lucky enough to make it work in my project!

Can you please provide some solutions?

Comment: can you post the template that didn't work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works based on your code. You need `[(ngModel)]` in the `ion-list` tag.

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="content" >
    <ion-item class="listItems">
        <ion-label>Option 1</ion-label>
        <ion-radio checked="false" value="Option1"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="listItems">
        <ion-label>Option 2</ion-label>
        <ion-radio checked="false" value="Option2"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="listItems">
        <ion-label>Option 3</ion-label>
        <ion-radio checked="false" value="Option3"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <h *ngIf="content=='Option1'"> Option 1</h>
    <h *ngIf="content=='Option2'"> Option 2</h>
    <h *ngIf="content=='Option3'"> Option 3</h>
```